# Highlight cells if found the same setting by comparing each tab in Excel

Tags: excel, dataset, compare

I have two tabs and each tab contains different permission roles and its settings. However, the main category and it's setting items are listed in one column. The main category is just highlighted in bold. I have no idea on how I can compare each tab, then highlight the setting item that are the same from each tab under the same category.

For example, the item "Include Inactive Employees in the search" under the People Admin Regional tab, it is highlighted in green because it is also existing on the other tab (EC Full Access Read Only) under the same category which is Manage Hires.

I hope that make sense. And sorry for asking this question and asking for the expert help on this matter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at conditional formatting?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I did, however when I combined the data of two tabs and use conditional formatting, there are some items within the same tab that are the same in which resulted to show also but technically, it not existing on the other tab.

Comment: use [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)